# How to fix " java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toString()"

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, mysql-workbench

everyone. I have recently started Java programming.

I am trying to make a school management system. In there, I received some error while entering marks in the report card section. I am not sure where I went wrong as the program compiles successfully. However, while clicking on save button, I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toString()" because the return value of "javax.swing.JTextField.getSelectedText()" is null

Here is what I have tried:

[CODE](https://codeshare.io/EBpYb8)

And Here is my MYSQL database:

[MYSQL DATABASE_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woZue.png)

[MYSQL DATABASE_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJzlu.png)

I will be really grateful for help/tip you can give me. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code directly in the question, not as an external link or as a picture. Then you can link to your code on external service, but most of what's needed to answer the question should be included in the question itself.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But unfortunately, I am still not able to solve the problem. The program compiles successfully, however I get a message saying "insertion failed" and "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toString()" because the return value of "javax.swing.JTextField.getSelectedText()" is null"

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: *"Yes, I saw that."* You saw what? The Q&A on the NPE? The page on the MRE? *SPIDERS?* Tip: Add @OHGODSPIDERS (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Don't post code on external sites, put it in the question itself.